# PHP DropboxUploader.php does not work for huge files

Tags: php

I have the following PHP code that lets me back up files to Dropbox:

```
// Dropbox username/password
$dropbox_email = 'xxxxxxxxxx';
$dropbox_pass = 'xxxxxxxxxxx';

include('DropboxUploader.php');
$uploader = new DropboxUploader($dropbox_email, $dropbox_pass);
$uploader->upload('backup-images.php','Backup/');
$uploader->upload($zipArchiveName,'Backup/');
```

File backup-images.php is around 1kb while $zipArchiveName is around 400Mb. I seem to mange to upload backup-images.php but not $zipArchiveName.

I tried using

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
```

I also tried modifying php.ini i.e. max_execution_time and the memory_limit but I can't seem to upload the huge file to dropbox. I have ample of space on my dropbox account.

In my case I donot wish to use the Dropbox SDK but DropboxUploader.php found [here](https://github.com/jakajancar).

I'd like suggestions or reasons why this isn't working or ideas how to get around it.

Answer (score 0):

One way you can go around this issue by splitting your backup file into multiple files. TAR archiver has a way to create multi-part archives. Take a look: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21373/can-i-automate-tars-multi-volume-feature

Comment: Thanks. I'll give your solution a try. So you're suggesting that 300Mb file may be too big for the server to handle, please?

Comment: Yes, it might be too big for the hosting environment where you're running; or your internet connection is too unstable; there are many other reasons why it might fail. Splitting the file into 10-meg chunks is simple and should solve things.

Comment: So how can I modify this to spit it into smaller chunks please?system("tar -czvf $backup_files $siteroot");

Answer (score 0):

There is a constant in that class that provides upload size limit at this line:

```
const DROPBOX_UPLOAD_LIMIT_IN_BYTES = 314572800;
```

This is 300MB.  So this class should throw an Exception in the following portion of code for a 400MB file:

```
    $filesize = filesize($source);
    if ($filesize < 0 or $filesize > self::DROPBOX_UPLOAD_LIMIT_IN_BYTES) {
        throw new Exception("File '$source' too large ($filesize bytes).", self::CODE_FILESIZE_TOO_LARGE);
    }
```

Are you not seeing this this Exception in error logs?

I don't know if that is the true current limit for this Dropbox API.  You may want to check their documentation to see if you can bump up the max size constant.

Comment: @user3173207 Do you have error logging turned on? If not, you should.

Comment: The files I'm using from github i.e. DropboxUploader doesn't seem tohave a file restriction

Comment: @user3173207 I went to the Github link you posted and looked right at that class and pulled the code samples above from it.  Perhaps you are using an older version which does not have this restriction and your call is failing on the actual Dropbox API.

Comment: You''re right. I updated my DropboxUploader.php and changed the limit to 1048576000 bytes to play around with it to see how it works. Thank you.

Comment: @user3173207 You should check Dropbox API documentation to understand current upload limits.